# How do I change @makeschapterhead to center the title of chapter?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, chapters

I redefined `\@makechapterhead` to short the space after and before a chapter title, but i don't know how to center it... any help?

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \normalsize\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %%%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 4):

To center the entire chapter heading construction, just replace `\raggedright` (the current/typical alignment style of the headings) with `\centering`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \normalsize\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %%%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \centering
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```