# how can I reduce space before and after the title of list of figure?

Tags: spacing

How can I center, change the fontsize and reduce the space after and before the title of list of figures, list of table and content? Can I change a macros like @makechapterhead?

Comment: `\listoffigures` usually sets as a `\chapter*`... and you just changed `\@makeschapterhead` in [How do I change `\@makeschapterhead` to center the title of chapter?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241514/5764)... I don't get how this would be different?

Comment: well I did, and it doesn't change, the chapters title change but the title of list of figure, tables and content are not changing, it keeps with the old font... it's strange

Comment: That's unfortunate. Please show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your current problem. No code snippets please. Something that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see "Tadaa!" - exactly what you're experiencing as the problem.

Comment: @KarlaPineda, note that there are 2 almost similar commands: `\@makeschapterhead` and `\@makechapterhead`. The first contains `s` for **stared**. Be careful.

Comment: You might consider trying with `titlesec`, as it allows for a different formatting/spacing for numbered and unnumbered chapters, sections, &c.

Comment: @Sigur your comment was the solution for me! Anybody having the same issue as I, i.e. that the chapter headings change but the List headings dont: do the same thing for `\@makeschapterhead` as you did for `\@makechapterhead`. You could maybe turn your comment into an answer, detailing what the differences are :)